# converting ipython notebook to html to share with others (missing pywin32)

Tags: python, windows, export, ipython

I have a notebook I would like to convert to export it as either: 1) HTML or --template full (default) which is very similar to the interactive view.

http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/nbconvert.html

When I run the command:

```
ipython nbconvert --to html MyNotebook.ipynb
```

No errors seem to pop up, but I can't find an additional notebook in the folder where my ipynb are stored?

Then if I try File > Download as > HTML I get the error: (even though I have the windows binary found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/4jci5y59/pywin32-219.win-amd64-py3.4.exe) installed).

```
full nbconvert failed: you need to have pywin32 installed for this to work
```

Comment: Do you have more than one Python installed?

Comment: @MikeDriscoll - No mike, just python 3.4 inside a virtual machine. After installing pywin32 do I need to restart? I thought I wouldn't since other libraries have worked (installed via pip) without restarting.

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to restart. It normally works by just running the exe. Have you tried importing a module from the pywin32 package? Try doing this in the interpreter: `import win32print`. If you can an `ImportError`, then pywin32 is not installed correctly.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll Thanks Mike - I get an ImportError, but I have tried installing it via 1) windows binary on my virtual machine and 2) via pip. Are there any other methods of installing pywin32 I could try. I would really like to export and share my notebook.

Comment: The windows binary is the way to go. I don't think you can install it with pip. When you run the binary, it should ask you where to install it. Are you sure you have the right one? For example, you cannot install a 64-bit pywin32 with a 32-bit Python version.

Comment: Hey Thanks for all your help Mike. I was able to export to HTML now.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python installation, some reasons, may not have installed nbconvert. Re-installing Anaconda3 did not help my case. 
I recommend that you install 'pandoc' that converts all kinds of file formats. It works in the command line mode and through ipython notebook file menu, as well. An easiest way to install pandoc in windows, visit the web site below;

http://www.texts.io/support/0004/

Blessings,
(a debtor)<><